# Windows 2008 Server R2- orginal Domain Profile will not show after username recovery

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain, user-accounts

One of our employees came back to our firm. His username in AD was deleted over a year ago, but the his domain profile on the computer he was using is still there. When he logs in a NEW domain profile is created on the same computer. Example the profile he was logging into was named Username000 and now a new profile was created name Username001 . How could he log into the domain profile: Username000 even though he was just created in AD?

Answer (score 5):

The profile is linked to a SID, which changed when the user was deleted and re-created in AD. The path of least resistance here is to copy the contents of the old profile to the new profile.

Comment: 30 seconds?!...

Comment: GOTTA BE NIMBLE TO BEAT ME!

Comment: ...True that ;)

Answer (score 3):

The user account is different (even though it is named the same) and he therefore doesn't have permissions to the old profile. Windows will not log the user into the old profile because it is a profile from a different user account.

If you want him to use the old profile then copy the old profile to the new profile.

Answer (score 1):

Use the User Profile Wizard software here: http://www.forensit.com/downloads.html

> User Profile Wizard 3.7 is the latest version of ForensiT's powerful
>   workstation migration tool. User Profile Wizard will migrate your
>   current user profile to your new domain account so that you can keep
>   all your existing data and settings.

It's very easy to follow and you can let him login with his new user account attached to the "old/original" profile.

Problem solved...and feel free to check it as the correct answer instead of joe's or marra's ;)